# How do I set up wireless radio time restriction in DD-WRT build 21061?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, dd-wrt

I upgraded to D-WRT specifically to get the ability to restrict wireless access on a schedule. I'm using a Netgear WNDR3700, and the install went flawlessly (as far as I can determine), but there is no "advanced wireless settings" tab in Wireless settings. There's another question here that shows a screenshot of the screen I want to get to ([DD-WRT Wireless Radio Time Restrictions](https://superuser.com/questions/195600/dd-wrt-wireless-radio-time-restrictions)) but I'm having no luck getting there.

I can find the Help screen for Advanced Wireless Settings (http://www.dd-wrt.com/help/english/HWirelessAdvanced.asp), which tells me I can access the Radio Times Restrictions page, via Google search - but I can't find the actual settings page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on build 22118, but was on a 20xxx some time before this, and the settings were in the same place. Here's a screenshot.
[DD-WRT Radio Time Restrictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRMaW.png)

Just in case the image isn't available: select Wireless on the top bar, WL0-Advanced (or WL1-Advanced or WL(n)-Advanced if you have more than one radio), then look for "Radio Time Restrictions", after the Advanced Settings section.